# How to polygonize NDVI raster using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, polygonize, vectorization

I have raster with NDVI values. I would like to polygonize the raster to get vector where each polygon is a pixel.
I have tried gdal.Polygonize as described in the [documentation](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#polygonize-a-raster-band) and that runs without any error, but the result is just the number 0. I'm not sure if there is way I can display /read the result, or even save it. This is how I did it:

```
src_ds = gdal.Open( "imgs/response.tiff" )
if src_ds is None:
    print ('Unable to open')
    sys.exit(1)
    

srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    

    
    
dst_layername = "POLYGONIZED_STUFF"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )


>>>
0
```

I believe maybe there is problem with the GetRasterBand, but couldn't display it either.

**My end goal is to be able to access the polygonized results**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would question the wisdom of vectorizing a raster containing NDVI values. The vector dataset is likely to be huge and unwieldy.

Having said that, a fast solution would be to convert your raster into XYZ format (***point coordinates***) using GDAL translate:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ NDVI.tif NDVI.xyz
```

If you really need polygons, you can do the following:

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal
import os

# open image:
im = gdal.Open('filename.tif')
srcband = im.GetRasterBand(1)

if srcband.GetNoDataValue() is None:
    mask = None
else:
    mask = srcband

# create output vector:
outfile = 'POLYGONIZED_STUFF.shp'
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

if os.path.exists(outfile):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outfile)

vector = driver.CreateDataSource(outfile)
layer = vector.CreateLayer(outfile.replace('.shp', ''), im.GetSpatialRef(), geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

# create field to write NDVI values:
field = ogr.FieldDefn('NDVI', ogr.OFTReal)
layer.CreateField(field)
del field

# polygonize:
gdal.Polygonize(srcband, mask, layer, 0, options=[], callback=gdal.TermProgress_nocb)

# close files:
del im, srcband, vector, layer
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly altering the accepted answer created polygons for negative pixel values for me:

```
mask = srcband.GetMaskBand()
```

I don't have enough reputation to just comment...